# Can't Sign into Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have Visual Studio 2013. It was licensed under a Microsoft partners/MSDN subscription and became expired. I re subscribed and have been signed out, but everytime I try to sign in I get

> The online service is not available. Please try again later.

Visual Studio online is indeed up and running, but I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, resetting all VS settings and still I can't sign in under any circumstances.

I am stuck not able to do any work because of this bug. How can I reset everything about VS so I can get this working?

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio 2013 Update 4? If not, I recommend installing it. Are there any relevant error messages in the windows event log? Which version operating system do you have? Which version of IE? Are there any available windows updates? Are you behind a proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Change the Visual Studio proxy settings in

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config

to

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
        <proxy usesystemdefault="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
    <settings>
        <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 is version 12.0 and updating that devenv.exe.config did not fix it for me.